# Use the generated decision tree to predict new inputs

Tags: c#, decision-tree, accord.net

I want to use the accord.net framework to generate a decision tree from a set of data.

I read the guide in this link http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2012/01/decision-trees-in-c.html

I was able to generate the tree by following it. However How to use it to predict new inputs?

what i mean is after creating the tree i want to use it (as a if-else statement to know the output of new inputs)

it is stated that I can convert it to an expression  `var expression = tree.ToExpression();` but how can I use it ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read the example in the guide carefully. At the very end of the procedure they generate the [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) with `var expression = tree.ToExpression();` **and compile it**:

`var func = expression.Compile();`

The result is a delegate that you can simply execute to get a decision for a given input. In the example, you could do something like

`bool willPlayTennis = func(new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}) == 1;`

Comment: Exactly. It is also possible to compute a decision for a given input using the decision tree's [Compute method](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/M_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_DecisionTree_Compute.htm). I agree the Compute example is missing; I should add it for further reference.

Comment: @Cesar, definitely need that example. I am doing the same thing with the Bayesian stuff, and it isn't apparent if I should use the same codebook to prepare the new inputs.

Comment: Just for further reference, the documentation page for the decision tree has been updated with a better example a while ago.